# the meaning of "few but"

Tags: meaning

*And most important, few but Professor Ettinger had seen the letters.*

I am not sure what the phrase "few but" exactly means. I tried to find the meaning on the internet but without any success. Given the context (Ettinger actually read the letters) I would understand it that Ettinger belonged to a minority of people who head read the letters. But if I apply to this phrase the same logic as to the similar one "all but", the meaning is rather different: few people read it but Ettinger not. So could you tell me which meaning is correct.

Comment: @Rathony: No, it doesn't mean that *only Professor Ettinger saw the letters*.  Others did, but they are few in number.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, you are right.

Comment: What does the dictionary tell you about *but*? Does it tell you that it can me *apart from* or *except*? (Did you consult a dictionary?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*But* here means *apart from*. *Few but Ettinger had seen the letters* means Ettinger and only a few others had seen the letters.